# Swap positions of Radios - Android java

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I got one RadioGroup with four Radios.

```
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    RadioButton r0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
```

I set the text to all of them.

```
    r0.setText("1");
    r1.setText("2");
    r2.setText("3");
    r3.setText("4");
```

So i got that radios like this 1, 2, 3, 4. How can I randomly swap positions of radios. I want to get something like this 3,2,1,4 or 2,3,1,4....etc...
But IMPORTANT I don't want to change text of radios, as I said I want positions to be swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this using the same layout XML file.

Use 4 different layouts, and inflate it randomly.

All your IDs will always work if you keep the same in each XML file.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  setContentView(randomLayout());

  RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
  // ...
}

public static int randomLayout() {
  final int n[] = { R.layout.layout1, R.layout.layout2, R.layout.layout3, R.layout.layout4 }
  Random random = new Random();
  return n[random.nextInt(n.length)];
}
```

Comment: It was just an example. You need 1 XML for each possible order. You cannot easily do otherwise, as fair as I know. The other alternative would be to play around with RelativeLayouts...

Comment: As I count there should be 24 combinations. But actually I need this swapping because one of the radio will be the true answer, other 3 false. So I need to swap position of true answer, false answers are not important, so 4 combination will be OK. --> TFFF, FTFF, FFTF, FFFT --> So thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

very quickely : 
if you don't have any idea,
try something on this way

something like...

```
int n = nb of radios;

RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

RadioButton r0 = new RadioButton(this);
RadioButton r1 = new RadioButton(this);
RadioButton rn = new RadioButton(this);

r0.setId(/*idr0*/);
r1.setId(/*idr1*/);
rn.setId(/*idrn*/);

r0.setText("text0");
rn.setText("textn");

ArrayList<RadioButton> e = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
e.add(r0);
e.add(rn);

Random rand = new Random();

while(n<0)
{
 int i = rand.nextInt(n);

 if (e.get(i) != null)
 { 
   rg.add(e.get(i));
   e.remove(i);
   n--;
 }
}
```

Comment: I got error on second "List" --> List<RadioButton> e = new List<RadioButton>(); --> Cannot instantiate the type List<RadioButton>

Comment: setId() is a solution I did not think about. It's clever, even tho I dont like to manipulate IDs from code, but still: nice point.